# Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking Modifications?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

Looking at adding Google Analytics E-commerce tracking to a website running on a closed source e-commerce platform. Google have given us this code as an example in their help system:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Receipt for your clothing purchase from Acme Clothing</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'Acme Clothing',  // affiliation or store name
    '11.99',          // total - required
    '1.29',           // tax
    '5',              // shipping
    'San Jose',       // city
    'California',     // state or province
    'USA'             // country
  ]);

   // add item might be called for every item in the shopping cart
   // where your ecommerce engine loops through each item in the cart and
   // prints out _addItem for each
  _gaq.push(['_addItem',
    '1234',           // transaction ID - required
    'DD44',           // SKU/code - required
    'T-Shirt',        // product name
    'Green Medium',   // category or variation
    '11.99',          // unit price - required
    '1'               // quantity - required
  ]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); //submits transaction to the Analytics servers

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body>

  Thank you for your order.  You will receive an email containing all your order details.

</body>
</html>
```

Would this just be placed onto the final sale page or would I need to do anything to the data? Unsure as have never done this before, the site is running on php/mysql scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To implement GA ecommerce tracking, you'll need to know your cart variable names (orderTotal, orderArray, etc - varies for every cart platform) and how to insert them into the script when the thank-you page is rendered, so that the customer's order has correct details.

Generally, you'd insert all of the addTrans variables, then perform a loop (one pass for each item in the cart) for addItem. But, the details of this really depend on your cart, so I can't be much more specific than that.

Depending on the size/savvy of your cart's community, you may be able to find a pre-cooked example that you can drop onto your thank-you page template, or it may even have this built in as a module.